# Swift - How to get rid of this dark background in UISearchController?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I got this dark background:

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H6j5.png)

Here are my codes:

```
class SearchController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self as? UISearchResultsUpdating
        self.definesPresentationContext = true

        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        self.definesPresentationContext = true

    }

}
```

What should I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this

```
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller

Comment: @VictorLi have given you the reputation